# How can I get two non-repeated random objects from an array at first render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blackjack, playing-cards

I'm making a simple app that will simulate a hand of blackjack. I've got the 'hit' functionality (getting one random card), but I'm struggling with getting the two initial random, non repeated cards on first render. I feel like there must be a more elegant solution to what I have in mind (not to mentions it's not working).

I would appreciate any direction on this, since I'm not sure why filtering and updating the original array isn't working.

Here's the code snippet:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
//import useCards from '../hooks/useCards'
import Card from '../components/Card';
import Total from '../components/Total';
import {deckArray} from '../utils/data'

export default function Home(){
    const [dealCards, setDealCards] = useState(false)
    const [usersCards, setUsersCards] = useState([])
    const [deck, setDeck] = useState(deckArray)
    const [isReset, setIsReset] = useState(true)
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)
    const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(dealCards===true){
            const randomCard = deck[Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length)];
            const newCardsArray = deck.filter(el => el.index !== randomCard.index)
            const chosenCardArray = deck.filter(el => el.index === randomCard.index)

            const chosenCard = chosenCardArray[0]
            setDeck(newCardsArray)
            setUsersCards(prevCards => [...prevCards, chosenCard])
            console.log(newCardsArray.length)
            setDealCards(false)
        }
    }, [usersCards, dealCards, deck])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isReset){
            setUsersCards([])
            setDeck(deckArray)
            setDealCards(false)
            setTotal(0)
        }
    },[isReset])


    //function to generate two random cards when user presses 'play'
    useEffect(() => {
        if(isStarted){
            //generate two random cards
            const randomCard = deck[Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length)];
            const newCardsArray = deck.filter(el => el.index !== randomCard.index)
            const chosenCardArray = deck.filter(el => el.index === randomCard.index)
            const chosenCard = chosenCardArray[0]
            setDeck(newCardsArray)
            setUsersCards(prevCards => [...prevCards, chosenCard])

            const randomCard1 = deck[Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length)];
            const newCardsArray1 = deck.filter(el => el.index !== randomCard1.index)
            const chosenCardArray1 = deck.filter(el => el.index === randomCard1.index)
            const chosenCard1 = chosenCardArray1[1]
            setDeck(newCardsArray1)
            setUsersCards(prevCards => [...prevCards, chosenCard1])
            console.log(newCardsArray1.length)
            setDealCards(false)
        }
    }, [isStarted, deck, dealCards])

    return (
        <>
            <Card usersCards={usersCards} />

            {!isStarted && <button onClick={() => setIsStarted(true)}>PLAY</button>}

            {isStarted && <>
            <Total usersCards={usersCards} total={total} setTotal={setTotal}/>
            <button onClick={() => setDealCards(true)}>HIT</button>
            <button>STAND</button>
            <button onClick={() => setIsReset(true)}>RESET</button>
            </>}
            
        </>
    )
}
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I'd avoid those double set state calls. Why not shuffle the cards array and pick the first or last two?

Comment: Yes, I was sure that this solution isn't the best. I'll try doing that, however my issue is also with the fact that the cards have to be there at the first render and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Instead of `useState(deckArray)`, you can't do `useState(shuffled(deckArray))`, where `shuffled()` is a standard [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)? I think you're overusing `useEffect`s here. If you want something to happen, instead of triggering a render with, say, `dealCards`, which then triggers a `useEffect` that deals the cards and sets state yet again, just make it a function `dealCards` that deals the cards and sets state, skipping the extra render.

Comment: What about adding and removing the cards? Do I do it in the shuffled function?

Comment: Do you mean taking hits? I added an answer that hopefully clarifies what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes, I mean keep adding until the total is 22 or more, I have to remove the cards already picked from the original array. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Yeah, once the deck is shuffled, you just keep a counter of how many have been drawn from the top, as shown in my answer. It's just like a normal deck of cards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250740/discussion-between-01nowicj-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code here is overusing `useEffect` to implement logic that should be done with simple event handlers. Only use `useEffect` when you're dealing with things that can't be determined before the render, like network calls, or depend on a reference to a DOM element outside of the normal rendering flow, like drawing on a `<canvas>`. These are side effects because they don't directly pertain to building the current render which the rest of the component body is working towards.

I don't have your utility and component imports, but here's an example that you should be able to adapt to your use case.

```js
// utility library "import"
const cards = (() => {
  const shuffle = a => {
    a = a.slice();

    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = ~~(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const x = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = x;
    }

    return a;
  };

  const frz = (...args) => Object.freeze(...args);
  const suits = frz([..."HCSD"]);
  const faces = frz([..."AJQK"]);
  const pips = frz([...Array(9)].map((_, i) => i + 2));
  const ranks = frz([...pips, ...faces]);
  const cards = frz(
    suits.flatMap(s => ranks.map(r => frz({
      rank: r,
      suit: s,
      str: r + s,
      value: isNaN(r) ? (r === "A" ? 11 : 10) : r,
    })))
  );
  const shuffled = () => shuffle(cards);
  return {shuffled};
})();

const Game = () => {
  const startHandSize = 2;
  const [deck, setDeck] = React.useState(cards.shuffled());
  const [cardsDealt, setCardsDealt] =
    React.useState(startHandSize);

  const deal = () => {
    setCardsDealt(startHandSize);
    setDeck(cards.shuffled());
  };

  const hit = () => !bust && setCardsDealt(prev => prev + 1);

  const cardsInPlay = deck.slice(-cardsDealt);
  const total = cardsInPlay.reduce((a, e) => a + e.value, 0);
  const bust = total > 21;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={deal}>Deal</button>
      <button disabled={bust} onClick={hit}>
        Hit
      </button>
      <div>
        {cardsInPlay.map(e => (
          <div key={e.str}>{e.str}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>Total: {total}</div>
      <div>{bust && "Bust!"}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Game />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```