# How can I evaluate each element in array and use useState() on one condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, blackjack, playing-cards

I'm making a blackjack hand simulation and I've encountered an issue with my code.
The game goes like this: users gets two random cards and a total of the points, clicks 'hit' to get another random card from the deck. Now that's all working but there's one more rule: if that card is an Ace, user chooses if they want to get 1 or 10 points. I implemented it before when I only had one card at a time with useEffect, however now I refactored my code and the total isn't kept in useState + the array has two cards that need to evaluated, not the most recent one.

I've tried putting my loop and if statement in a useEffect and conditionally render the Popup to let the user decide (with and without dependencies), but when I put the useState() to trigger the condition, it throws an error that there have been too many renders and I'm not sure why that is.

Here's my Home component:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Card from '../components/Card';
import Total from '../components/Total';
import Popup from '../components/Popup'

import {shuffle} from '../hooks/shuffleCards'
import {deckArray} from '../utils/data'
export default function Home(){
    const startHandSize = 2
    const [starterDeck, setStarterDeck] = useState(shuffle(deckArray))
    const [howManyDealt, setHowManyDealt] = useState(startHandSize)
    const [triggerPopup, setButtonPopup] = useState(false)

    const deal = () => {
        setHowManyDealt(startHandSize)
        setStarterDeck(shuffle(deckArray))
    }

    const hit = () => !bust && setHowManyDealt(prev => prev + 1)

    const usersCards = starterDeck.slice(-howManyDealt)

    var total = 0

    usersCards.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
        if(arrayItem.card === "A"){
            alert("you have an ace") 
        }
        else{
            total += arrayItem.value
        }
    });

    const bust = total > 21;

    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={deal}>DEAL</button>
            <button disabled={bust} onClick={hit}>HIT</button>
            <button disabled={bust}>STAND</button>
            <Total total={total} usersCards={usersCards}/> 
            <Card usersCards={usersCards}/>

            {triggerPopup && <Popup total={total} setButtonPopup={setButtonPopup}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and my Popup:

```
export default function Popup({total, setButtonPopup}){
   const handleClick = (points) => {
    total += points
    setButtonPopup(false)
   }

    return(
        <div className="popup">
            <div className="popup-inner">
            <h4>You've got an Ace. Would you like to collect 1 or 10 points?</h4>
            <button className=".btn-popup" onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>1 POINT</button>
            <button className=".btn-popup" onClick={() => handleClick(10)}>10 POINTS</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Good attempt. However, there seems to be a general misunderstanding about state. Consider this code:

```js
const handleClick = (points) => {
  total += points
  setButtonPopup(false)
}
```

`total` is a purely local variable to `Popup`, so this `+=` pretty much does nothing. To change state in the caller, you'd normally pass a callback that can trigger a `setState` and move the new value for `total` into state.

Remember: any data change must happen immutably, and if you want to trigger a re-render, you have to set state. Of course, there are ways to circumvent this flow using refs and so forth, but these are escape hatches you shouldn't use if you don't have to.

However, a design with `total` kept in state strikes me as redundant. We already know the total based on the cards in play. A better strategy seems to be having ace values individually settable via the popup modal, assuming you don't want to [auto-compute these ace values to be as high as possible without busting](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31423/can-different-aces-have-different-values/31475#31475) or use a toggle switch instead of a modal.

I kept going with [my code from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955161/how-can-i-get-two-non-repeated-random-objects-from-an-array-at-first-render-in-r/74956072#74956072) and added the modal. I'm treating high aces as 11 per the rules of Blackjack, but you can easily make that 10 if you want.

As before, I'm hoping you can apply the techniques here to your code. The keys are the `handleAceSet` callback and the new piece of state `aceToSet`, which is a ace the user has picked, or null if the user hasn't chosen an ace. `aceToSet` is like your `setButtonPopup`, but tracks an object or null rather than a boolean. When `aceToSet` isn't null, the user has selected an ace and we show the modal to let them pick a value for it.

`handleAceSet` may seem a bit complex, but it has to be due to immutability. It finds the index of the ace the user wants to set in the deck array, then creates a new object at this index with the new value and glues the subarray slices before and after the index back together.

```js
// utility library "import"
const cards = (() => {
  const shuffle = a => {
    a = a.slice();

    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = ~~(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const x = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = x;
    }

    return a;
  };

  const frz = (...args) => Object.freeze(...args);
  const suits = frz([..."HCSD"]);
  const faces = frz([..."AJQK"]);
  const pips = frz([...Array(9)].map((_, i) => i + 2));
  const ranks = frz([...pips, ...faces]);
  const cards = frz(
    suits.flatMap(s =>
      ranks.map(r =>
        frz({
          rank: r,
          suit: s,
          str: r + s,
          value: isNaN(r) ? (r === "A" ? 1 : 10) : r,
        })
      )
    )
  );
  const shuffled = () => shuffle(cards);
  return {shuffled};
})();

const {Fragment, useState} = React;

const AceSetterModal = ({handleSetLow, handleSetHigh}) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleSetLow}>Set ace low</button>
    <button onClick={handleSetHigh}>Set ace high</button>
  </div>
);

const Card = ({card, handleAceSet}) => (
  <div>
    {card.str}
    {card.rank === "A" && (
      <Fragment>
        {" "}
        <button onClick={handleAceSet}>
          Set ({card.value})
        </button>
      </Fragment>
    )}
  </div>
);

const Game = () => {
  const startHandSize = 2;
  const goal = 21;
  const lowAce = 1;
  const highAce = 11;
  const [deck, setDeck] = useState(cards.shuffled());
  const [cardsDealt, setCardsDealt] = useState(startHandSize);
  const [aceToSet, setAceToSet] = useState(null);

  const handleAceSet = value => {
    setDeck(deck => {
      const i = deck.findIndex(e => e.str === aceToSet.str);
      return [
        ...deck.slice(0, i),
        {...aceToSet, value},
        ...deck.slice(i + 1),
      ];
    });
    setAceToSet(null);
  };

  const deal = () => {
    setCardsDealt(startHandSize);
    setDeck(cards.shuffled());
  };

  const hit = () => !bust && setCardsDealt(prev => prev + 1);

  const cardsInPlay = deck.slice(-cardsDealt);
  const total = cardsInPlay.reduce((a, e) => a + e.value, 0);
  const bust = total > goal;

  return (
    <div>
      {aceToSet ? (
        <AceSetterModal
          handleSetLow={() => handleAceSet(lowAce)}
          handleSetHigh={() => handleAceSet(highAce)}
        />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <button onClick={deal}>Deal</button>
          <button disabled={bust} onClick={hit}>
            Hit
          </button>
          <div>
            {cardsInPlay.map(e => (
              <Card
                key={e.str}
                handleAceSet={() => setAceToSet(e)}
                card={e}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
          <div>Total: {total}</div>
          <div>{bust && "Bust!"}</div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Game />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to adapt it, but I have my array of cards hard-coded with pre-set values (such as {
      suits: "Heart",
      card: "A",
      color: "red",
      index: "1",
      unicode: "",
      value: 0
    }. How can adapt it so that the value in aces changes after user picks it?

Comment: There's no way to change the `.value` on the card with a state set similar to mine? If not, you could add a second data structure that lets you look up the value for an ace. You need to track it somewhere, unless after the user sets it high or low, it's always that value, which would be the case if you kept the total in state and permanently added 1 or 11 to it when the user picks its value.

Comment: So could I just keep the total as state somehow? Would that be better?

Comment: It seems less flexible to do it that way. My understanding in BJ is that picking the value of an ace isn't a permanent decision. You can think of any ace as high or low at any time, and the player will always be assumed to make the optimal choice. So if the player is dealt 2 aces, they'll want to set one high and one low. If they're dealt a queen next, they'll want to set aces low. Your code will then have to decrement 10 from the total and sort of infer whether the previous aces were high or not in the first place. It just seems too fussy to me relative to each card tracking its own value.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, it'd be best if the BJ game just computed the optimal ace values automatically--make them as high as possible without busting, which is easy to do. Assume all are high, and then if it's bust, lower an ace and check again. If it's still bust, lower another ace. Repeat until lowering an ace causes it to stop being bust, or until the player runs out of aces to lower, in which case they're definitely busted.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but if I wanted to give the user a choice still? I just want to get it to work to learn how, I'm not that worried about it being completely correct when it comes to blackjack itself. But I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Yeah, well that's where my post offers my suggestion for how to do that, with the modal. Even though it seems unnecessary on a couple of levels, it's no less educational from a React perspective.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to keep my deck array how it is to get the unicode characters for the visual side of it. I'll keep fighting though!